# Exiftool "Focal length in 35 mm" is not copied from the src to destination

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to copy all the metadata from on photo to another using exiftool.
The web documents state: **exiftool.exe -TagsFromFile source destination**

When checking the metadata using AnalogExif, i can see that :
**flag "Focal length in 35 mm" is missing.**

Of course the information is present in the source file.

An idea ?

Comment: Is the tag there using exiftool?  
`exiftool -FocalLengthIn35mmFormat File.jpg`

Comment: Tested this and both Adobe Bridge and Irfanview do not see the copied tag, though exiftool finds it.

Comment: Very strange, now I can't reproduce this.  Can you share a file that doesn't show the tag?